# How to determine if a sentence is a statement using OpenNLP or any other library?

Tags: nlp, text-mining, opennlp

I am wondering if it's possible to determine if a sentence is a **Question** or a **Statement** using [Apache OpenNLP](https://opennlp.apache.org/) or any other library?

If so, I'm looking for some pointers on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Using a rule based engine you can look for the following information in the sentence to decide whether the sentence is a question or not:

- Start with 'Why', 'What',  'Who', 'When' or 'How'
- Verb comes before the subject
- There is a question mark at the end of the sentence.